# Express Response.send() throwing TypeError

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, npm

I have this simple express code:

```
const api = Router()

api.post('/some-point', async (req, res, next) => {
  const someStuffToSend = await Promise.resolve("hello");
  res.json({ someStuffToSend });
})
```

It works well on my dev environment, but on the prod I get the error bellow:

```
TypeError: argument entity must be string, Buffer, or fs.Stats
    at etag (/[...]/node_modules/etag/index.js:83:11)
    at generateETag ([...]/node_modules/express/lib/utils.js:280:12)
    at ServerResponse.send ([...]/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:200:17)
    at ServerResponse.json ([...]/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at api.post (/the/code/above)
```

I checked at `node_modules/etag/index.js:83:11` and saw

```
if (!isStats && typeof entity !== 'string' && !Buffer.isBuffer(entity)) {
  throw new TypeError('argument entity must be string, Buffer, or fs.Stats')
}
```

Before this code I added a printf to check the type of entity:

```
console.log("Entity contains", entity, "is of type", typeof entity, "with constructor", entity.constructor, "and is it a buffer?", Buffer.isBuffer(entity))
```

Which got me the output bellow:

```
Entity contains <Buffer 7b 22 70 72 65 64 69 63 74 69 6f 6e 5f 69 64 22 3a 22 63 4b 57 41 64 41 46 43 77 6e 55 43 22 2c 22 69 6e 69 74 69 61 6c 5f 70 72 65 64 69 63 74 69 6f ... > is of type object with constructor function Buffer(arg, encodingOrOffset, length) {
  if (!Buffer.TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT && !(this instanceof Buffer)) {
    return new Buffer(arg, encodingOrOffset, length)
  }

  // Common case.
  if (typeof arg === 'number') {
    if (typeof encodingOrOffset === 'string') {
      throw new Error(
        'If encoding is specified then the first argument must be a string'
      )
    }
    return allocUnsafe(this, arg)
  }
  return from(this, arg, encodingOrOffset, length)
} and is it a buffer? false
```

So it looks like the entity is a buffer, but not recognized as such. If I comment the test out, it crashed at a different location

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:747:13)
    at ServerResponse.send ([...]/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:221:10)
    at ServerResponse.json ([...]/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at api.post (/the/code/above)
```

If you check at `/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:221:10` you see

```
this.end(chunk, encoding);
```

where encoding is from a few lines above (l. 189, I checked with a printf)

```
chunk = Buffer.from(chunk, encoding)
```

I could hack the lib out to make that work, but I suspect some broken `node_modules` folder. However the error persists even after a `rm package-lock.json; rm -rf node_modules; npm i`.

Any clue on how to solve this would be very appreciated.

Below are my version numbers:

- node 9.8.0 (also tried with 8.4.0), installed locally with nvm
- npm 5.6.0
- express 4.16.3
- ts-node 5.0.1
- typescript 2.7.2

**Edit 1**

- replace the async call by something simpler
- specify express version

**Edit 2**

I removed the `node_modules` folder then `npm i` the packages one by one:

```
npm i aws-sdk body-parser bunyan check-types deepcopy duck-type express fast-csv glob handlebars http-auth md5 moment moment-timezone multer node-stream object-path randomstring
```

Still get the same error.

**Edit 3**

Add further information about the environment.

**Edit 4**

OK, figured out. It was a ts-node config related problem.
I was launching my server with

```
ts-node --harmony_async_iteration -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts
```

With the following lines in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [ "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "pretty": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*", "src/*", "src/types/*",
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [ "src/**/*" ]
}
```

Because of the `-r tsconfig-paths/register` in the command line, the paths specified in the `tsconfig.json` were loaded, including the `"node_modules/*"` in `paths['*']`.

I'm not sure why, but it looks like this was causing the libs in `node_modules` to be loaded twice, breaking the type checks based on constructors (such as `instanceof`).

**Question**

I'm not sure to completely understand the reason of that. Any light?

Comment: What exactly does `someAsyncFunc()` resolve to?  Can you show us the code for that?

Comment: Also, what version of Express are you running in production?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I replaced the async call by a `Promise.resolve()` and it still crashed with the same error. I also the Express version (4.16.3 on both prod and dev)

Comment: I'd suggest clearly all the dependent modules and reloading them cleanly from NPM.

Comment: Let me install all of them one by one...

Comment: I installed all my packages by hand (edit 2) Still the same error

Comment: @AntoineTrouve But the log statement said `and is it a buffer? false`, it turns out it's NOT a buffer, it's an object but expected is String, Buffer or fs.Stats. I'm just making sure if I understand the problem correctly here. Because you wrote "So it looks like the entity is a buffer," which doesn't seem so from the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar issue with `typeorm` and later with `express` too. The hint was in [this conversation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2084). My solution was to get rid `*` from `paths`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error,

```
TypeError: argument entity must be string, Buffer, or fs.Stats
    at etag (/[...]/node_modules/etag/index.js:83:11)
    at generateETag ([...]/node_modules/express/lib/utils.js:280:12)
    .....
```

I was trying to run a express project, and using webpack as bundler,

My error got resolved when I set target in webpack as **'node'**

```
module.exports = (env) => {
    return {
      //....
      target: "node",
      //....,
      plugins: [
        // new NodePolyfillPlugin() // Don't add this plugin
       ]
    
    }
}
```

And make sure not to add `NodePolyfillPlugin` as pluging